# Grails password constraint function

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to require users to enter a 'passphrase' since they are more secure than typical passwords people come up with.

I'm using

```
int numberOfWords = password.collect { 
    it.charAt(0).digit || it.charAt(0).letter ? it : ' ' 
}.join('').tokenize(' ').size()
numberOfWords >= 3
```

To make sure that the user creates as password containing at least 3 words to ensure security. How would I include this logic in my constraints?
I tried making this into a method then just calling the method inside of constraints, but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your logic/code is correct, you could include the constraint like so.

```
  static constraints = {
    ...
    password blank: false, validator: { value, obj ->
      int numberOfWords = value.collect {....//your logic/code

      if(numberOfWords < 3) {
        //returns custom error msg with this key in message.properties
        return 'className.propertyName.passphrase.validation.msg'
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a link to [validator info](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)

Comment: Ahhhhhh, so this is how validators work. Dang, I thought they were something completely different. Thank you so much!!!